# When I try to delete list I got a list size greater than list size+1

Tags: java

```
List<Studentdb> list = teacherDao.viewstudent(facultyid, batchid1);
System.out.println("" + list);
int i = 0;
for (Iterator<Studentdb> s = list.iterator(); s.hasNext(); ) {
     System.out.println("" + i);
     System.out.println("list========" + list.get(i).getRoll());
     if (teacherDao.viewmarks(subjectcode, list.get(i).getRoll())) {
           list.remove(s);
     }
    i++;
}
```

When I try to delete a selected list i get the error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3`.

Here I have list size `3` i.e index `0 1 2` and I got the error in index `3`.

Comment: For better help sooner post a valid [mcve]

Comment: It seems you're missing the call to `s.next()`.

Comment: What is the point of `Iterator<Studentdb> s = list.iterator()` if you are using `list.get(i)`? Use `iterator.next()` to get current element, test its properties and depending on result decide if you want to remove it or not. Or simpler use `list.removeIf(filteringPredicate)`

Comment: "...decide if you want to remove it or not" BTW removal should be done via iterator, not via `list`. Otherwise you can also face ConcurrentModificationException explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

Comment: #Pshemo i am sure that i want to remove a list

Comment: @sanjay your code is not removing list, but element *from* list. Removal can be done via iterator, and should be done by it. Simply use `Studentdb student = s.next(); if (..thisStudendShouldBeRemoved..){s.remove()};`.

Comment: BTW on Stack Overflow to ping specific user use `@userName` not `#userName`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing items from lists in a for loop is always a mess.

It's best to place the desired items in another list, or if using Java 8 use streams and filter the list.

Answer (score 0):

You're code has an infinite loop because it doesn't get the next item in the iterator.

So, by the time `i` is equal to `3` you're code is trying to get the 4th element in the list, which it's why you're getting this exception.

You should call the `next()` method in your `s` object.

Comment: s.next() get error in studentdb cannot be converted to boolean

Comment: You need to call it in this line `list.remove(s);` -> `list.remove(s.next());`

Answer (score 0):

Just include a condition such that it breaks, after reaching at the position size-1.
And i hope u know very well that if the size of a list is n, the list gets indexing from 0 to n-1.
In your error message, what it actually says is that, Your are trying to iterate to an item which is out of the allocated area of the list.

Comment: as per your suggestion i found my list doesn't remove #Goutham